# вывод асинхронных данных react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

Всем привет. Имею компонент Notes

```
 class Notes extends Component {
 componentDidMount(){
    this.props.axiosNotes(); //получаю данные с сервера 
}
render(){
    const notes = this.props.notes;
    console.log(notes); //у момент создания компонента = {}, после 
                        //срабатывания axiosNotes = {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 
                        //  3: {…}, 4: {…}}
    return(
        <div>
            {notes.map(i => <p>{i.title}</p>), 2000)} //map is not a function
        </div>
    )
 }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
notes: state.notes
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
axiosNotes
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Notes);
```

Вообщем, так как я получаю данные асинхронно, мой пропс notes сначала пустой объект, а метод map не может итерироваться по пустому объекту. Вопрос, как мне вывести данные this.props.notes не у момент создания компонента, а когда пришли асинхронные данные, т.е. когда notes.length > 0

Comment: Все же как обычно делается: ставим флаг в стейте, как только получаем данные - стэйт становится true. И на это изменение триггерится рендер и срабатывает функция с мапом.

Comment: так? если да, то не работает, через тернарник тоже
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
           notes: state.notes && state.notes
       });

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверять через jsx тернарник на наличие данных и в случае, если данные существуют (пришли, были получены), то рендерить необходимую часть компонентов.
В примере показано как мы получаем данные (имитируя запрос в 3 секунды), после чего наш state получает данные и страница рендерит их:

```js
const { Component } = React;

const dataToReceive = [
 {
  name: 'John',
  skill: 'HTML'
 },
 {
  name: 'Bill',
   skill: 'Javascript'
 }
]

class App extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
   data: null,
  }
 }
  
 componentDidMount() {
  this.requestData(dataToReceive)
 }
  
 requestData(data) { 
  new Promise((res, rej) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
    res(data);
     }, 3000);  
  })
  .then(result => {
   this.setState({
    data: result,
   })
  })
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    { !this.state.data && 
     <div>Data is loading...</div>
    }
    { this.state.data &&
     <div>
      <div>Data successfully loaded</div>
      
      {this.state.data.map(item => {
       return (
        <div>Name: {item.name}</div>
       )
      })}
     </div>
    }
   </div>
  )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```