# React с запросами к серверу без redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

исследую возможности реакт. redux не использую по незнанию и отсутствию времени. Задача такова.
Есть две формы select, первая "курс", вторая "тема"
Поначалу форма темы скрыта и пустая, а в форму курса приходит значение от сервера при загрузке. На форму курса повешено событие, которое делает запрос к бд. Сутью запроса является, выбрать все темы выбранного курса и соответственно после этого необходимо от рисовать форму темы.
Проблема я полагаю в том, что даже если задать метод, который будет менять состояние, то возникает проблема, рендер то синхронный, а данные приходят из асинхронного обещания. В общем у меня рендерит пустоту.
Я отлично понимаю, что делаю кучу костылей и подобные задачи хорошо бы возложить на механизм redux, но хочу узнать хотя бы концептуально, как это сделать на чистом React

Comment: вот здесь совсем недавно ответил на похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914513/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-react-redux?noredirect=1#comment1505816_914513

Answer (score 0):

Асинхронные запросы без redux вплоне имеют себе место на жизнь вместе c React: [демо](https://www.blairanderson.co/react-no-redux/) и вот его [код](https://github.com/blairanderson/react-no-redux/blob/master/src/AsyncExample.js).

Но Вы правильно поняли что это не совсем тот путь которым надо идти. В большом проекте Вам будет сложно манипулировать состояниями и событиями, лучше возложить это на Redux.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно глянув в код вам станет более понятна логика работы с БД внутри компонента

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ThemesList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      themes: [],
      isLoading: true
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      themes: await getThemes(), // где getThemes это ваша функция для получения данных из БД (в этом примере я предполагаю что она возвращает массив тем)
      isLoading: false
    })
  }


  render() {
    const { isLoading, themes } = this.state

    if (isLoading) return <div>Loader...</div>
    return(
      <ul>
        {themes.map(theme => <li key={theme.id}>{theme.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```